# Select value with odd chars from mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a field in a mysql database with a strange value:

```
    ????!"?;%:?*()_+,??????/????\/
```

The problem is I cannot select it - the following statement returns no rows

```
SELECT *
    FROM `pool_tag` AS `Extent1`
    where `Extent1`.`PoolTag`='????!"?;%:?*()_+,??????/????\/'
```

The value contains "

I was trying also to use rule to duplicate cotation sign, so used this sql

```
SELECT *
    FROM `pool_tag` AS `Extent1`
    where `Extent1`.`PoolTag`="????!**""**?;%:?*()_+,??????/????\/"
```

(note double cotation marks on position 6)

But still no result

The other problem might be, even if I find a specific syntax to handle in sql query directly, I need to select this from Entity Framework (actually the query you saw wa generated by EF)

Any idea how to handle this?

---

**EDIT**

I found about mysql escape chars, I checked all one by one (", ', \, %) and I dicovered that % cause the problems.

If I remove it from both field and search value, sql works

If I leave it in field, and try to escape it in sql select, code still don't work

e.g.

```
SELECT *
    FROM `pool_tag` AS `Extent1`
    where `Extent1`.`PoolTag`="????!?;\%:?"
```

does not find the value

```
????!?;%:?
```

Any idea why?

Comment: The question marks are likely characters that cannot be represented in the connection encoding. Are you trying to store binary data in that column, or is this a broken record that you are trying to fix?

Comment: App is in a test phase, a tested entered such vakues ina  field (which is just a tags string) and now he tested deleting that when we found this situation

Comment: What dpes [`HEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) say is in that string?

Comment: It returns '3F3F3F3F21223F3B253A3F2A28292B2C3F3F3F3F3F3F2F3F3F3F3F2F'. But I cannot search using Hex because the actual search is done in EF, using Linq to entities

Comment: OK, the problem is, this ends in `?/`, your search terms and claims say it ends in `\/`, which meanse somewhere in your code there is a process which thinks it needs to escape `/`'s while it doesn't.

Comment: BTW, this is the string according to my UNHEX: `????!"?;%:?*()+,??????/????/`.